# Endless queues with auto-generated names keep being created

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-websocket

This is the image reg... queues generated automatically with random names

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, this is what you want

```
public static String getRandomString(int length) {
    char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST".toCharArray();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
        sb.append(c);
    }
    String randomStr = sb.toString();

    return randomStr;
}
```

you need to call this function with enqueue like this.

```
Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<>();
q.add(getRandomString(10));
```

Comment: present random queues are created ....i need to stop creating random queues and as well as i want to create only queues are binded with what ever exchanges are there to linkup with routing-key ...

Comment: @kumar for the queue resume and break please refer this link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Comment: i am using rabbit-mq @Kishan... and spring-boot i need to stop creating queue frm rabbitmq management ..... like what ever image i tagged to the question